# How to install seamsh in python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, gdal

I tried to install seamsh 0.4.4(https://pypi.org/project/seamsh/) but counld not.
I spent a lot of time on it.

I needed gdal library to use seamsh.
So I installded it by conda because it was too complex to install it without conda.

But conda was not supported seamsh, so I don't know what to do.
Could you tell me how to install seamsh?

I use windows and vscode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a pending PR to add it to Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/20966). In the meantime, one can install it from PyPI. For example, try using the following environment:

**seamsh.yaml**

```yaml
name: seamsh
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults  # only use conda-forge
dependencies:
  ## core software
  - python=3.10  # set to preference
  - pip

  ## libraries
  - gdal

  ## Conda Python packages
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - python-gmsh >=4.10  # used to ensure latest version

  ## PyPI Python packages
  - pip:
    - seamsh
```

Create with:

```bash
conda env create -n seamsh -f seamsh.yaml
```

At least on macOS, I'm seeing pip reinstall the Python `gmsh` package, despite the Conda Forge version being installed. Unsure why it isn't acknowledging the Conda version.

Comment: Thanks! I could install it and run the sample code, https://jlambrechts.git-page.immc.ucl.ac.be/seamsh/examples/1-simple.html !